# Enviar una petición GET con un body

Tags: angular

estoy intentando enviar un parámetro 'filter' como body en una petición get. Mi problema es que necesito enviar 3 parámetros (url, header, body) y sólo se me permite 2. Luego cuando sólo pruebo enviando solo la url y el body, el IDE me detecta que no es permitido el tipo filter en la petición.

A alguno le pasó esto?

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo que estas ocupando?

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo cambiando parte de código en el backend. Gracias.!

Answer (score 0):

En las peticiones de tipo GET no se debe enviar un parámetro body, pues el body solamente se debe dejar mandar cuando el tipo de petición es POST. Si la api a la que estás testeando requiere enviar un body, entonces es porque la petición es de tipo POST.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo cambiando parte de código en el backend. Gracias.!

Comment: Realmente por buenas prácticas no se debería de solicitar `Body` en un `get` pero eso no quiere decir que no se pueda hacer, ya que la diferencia entre `GET` y `POST` es que el primero debería ser para consulta de datos y el segundo para modificación, pero para `REST` no hay un estándar oficial de como hacer las cosas son más sugerencias que deberíamos seguir para ser homogéneos entre proyectos, un ejemplo de esto son las versiones en las API, muchos las utilizan en la `URL` pero otros las utilizan en el encabezado http.

Comment: Aun así hay que tener cuidado a la hora de elegir una librería para consumir `APIs` `REST` porque algunas permiten enviar `BODY` en el `GET` para tener flexibilidad y otras que siguen las buenas practicas al pie de la letra no, entonces cuando consumes a un tercero es mejor estar consientes de esta limitante porque ya me he encontrado con `Body` en los `GETs` y consumido `GETs` que funcionan como `POST` de una importante compañía a nivel mundial.